# Trigonometric functions on set of co-primes to $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

E.g. I plotted the function values of $y=\tan(x\frac{\pi}{n})$ for integer $x$-values in the range of $0,\cdots,n$ where $n$ is a given odd integer ( to prevent the case of undefined $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$. In this case I could find an argument why the curve is a symmetrical picture of one period of the $\tan$-function : one shifts the negative $x$-values by $n$.

Now I tried the plot on the $\phi(n)$ integers of the set 
$$E_n=\lbrace k\mid 1\le k\le n\ \&\ (k,n)=1\rbrace=U_n\cup O_n$$ 
where $U_n$ is the "lower part" subset of $\phi(n)/2$ numbers of $E_n$.
I was somehow astonished that I again got a symmetrical subgraph.

Is there some argument why the integers in the "upper part" $O_n$ give exactly the negative values of the lower branch. For me thats a surprise.
I find no way of proving it - for instance via a congruence calculation.

Comment: Because if $k$ is coprime to $n$ ( $k\in E_n$) then $n-k$ is coprime to $n$ ($n-k\in E_n$) and this gives us $\tan\left((n-k)\frac{\pi}{n}\right) = \tan\left(\pi-k\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=- \tan\left(k\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$

Comment: I think this is the answer. How would one argue that $n-k$ is also co-prime ?